# FastCGI one or multiple process?

Tags: c++, fastcgi

I am thinking about to develop a C++ module using FastCGI in order to make a calculation. I have multiple calculations, therefor multiple paths. I want try to find the best approach to implement it.

I would have:

```
http://127.0.0.1/api/calc1
http://127.0.0.1/api/calc2
http://127.0.0.1/api/calc3
```

I see 2 ways to do it:

1. Create one bin per calculation and use my webserver to do the
   routing
2. Create a single bin and do the routing in c++ to the different calculations

The first option would allow me to be much more flexible and its simple to develop, but more complicated to deploy. The second option seems to be the basic approach and might be easier to deploy.

I have about around 100 calculations.

What do you think about the options?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using FastCGI, instead of std::thread?

Comment: I think you should expand on your idea and explain what you are trying to solve.

Comment: evaluate the ratio computation-time vs transport-time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have no reason to use thread.

Comment: @graham.reeds I have to make some calculation in C++ accessible from a REST API. This is the reason why I want to use FastCGI in order t communicate with Nginx, Apache or ... This calculations process get data from a third party, make some +-/... between different value and return the result in JSON.

Comment: @norisknofun The transport-time will be the same in both case.

Comment: Why not use Casablanca?

Comment: @graham.reeds I thought about it and as well proxygen but fastcgi make it more flexible and allow me to choose any kind of webserver...

Comment: Using std::thread in a single process will offer more control over division of workload, and should be more flexible than building on top of independent FastCGI processes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik actually I don't really need multi-process/thread or at the moment... I was thinking about the first approach to be more flexible with the routing. For example with Nginx I can define all my route in the config file. Also if I have to update a calculation module, I can update only 1 module instead to have to recompile the all stuff. Anyhow at the end there is some advantage and some disadvantage in both case ;-) Thanks for your answers